# SPF VIM syntax on by default

Tags: vim, spf13vim

I just installed spf13 vim on my machine with CentOS. One thing I noticed is that I was not able to set "syntax on" by default. 
[image]

The difference are the parenthesis color and the GLOB color. The default color is very light on my monitor, so really want to set syntax on by default.

I am not sure what went wrong. Here is my ~/.vimrc.local

```
filetype plugin on
syntax on
```

Comment: Are you sure `~/.vimrc.local` is used?

Comment: I also added that to my  ~/.vimrc file, but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up vim defaults can be funky on new installs.

First, confirm that the rc is being sourced.

1. Place the line `echom "file is sourced on startup"` into your .vimrc.
2. Open a new instance of vim. Type `:messages` then `<return>`. If you don't see that line, the file isn't being sourced.

To find out where vim is looking for your .vimrc:

1. Enter the command `:echo $HOME`. The folder it outputs is a good place to try putting a `.vimrc` or `.vimrc.local` file. Try both of those.

   - Also try `:e $MYVIMRC`, which might find the file you need to edit anyway.

Finally, make sure to put `set nocompatible` in your rc.